# Opencart - Clean url for specific pages only

Tags: apache, .htaccess, opencart, opencart2.x

I am using Opencart and I have some static pages also.
I don't want to mess up opencart's SEO options so is there a way to create clean URLs only for specific pages?

What I want is :

```
http://example.com/my-custom-page.php
```

to

```
http://example.com/my-custom-page
```

I am using standart htaccess file comes with opencart package

I have these lines:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/download/(.*) index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to remove the .php extension in your url just use

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

or this

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

If .html then you can do

`RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]`

Comment: Same again. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

put the following code at main directory (root) `.htaccess` file :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} my-custom-page.php

# the line above to choose only my-custom-page.php and if you remove it
# the code will remove all php pages extensions

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R]
```

The code will remove my-custom-page.php extension and it would be my-custom-page regardless of its directory

Comment: Not working. Thanks anyway. I don't want to remove RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA] because opencart messes up all links

Comment: put it under all htaccess old rules and it should work and not affected any old rules , make sure you empty browser cache